# Java Swing passing instance of class vs anonymous class

Tags: java, swing, this, anonymous-class

I'm following a Swing tutorial and I found two ways to make the below code work.  Essentially we are creating a frame and placing buttons and a text area in it.  As far as I can tell they achieve the same functionality however I am curious as to what the difference is underneath/ if one would be a better approach for larger projects.

This is the way it was shown in the tutorial:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private TextPanel textPanel;
    private ButtonPanel buttonPanel;

    public MainFrame(String title){
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800,600);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        this.textPanel = new TextPanel();
        this.buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel();

        this.buttonPanel.setTextListener(new TextListener(){
            public void deliverText(String text) {
                textPanel.appendText(text);
            }
        });     

        this.add(textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
```

This is another approach I discovered while messing around with the code:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements TextListener{

    private TextPanel textPanel;
    private ButtonPanel buttonPanel;

    public MainFrame(String title){
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800,600);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.textPanel = new TextPanel();
        this.buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel();
        this.buttonPanel.setTextListener(this); 

        this.add(textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

     public void deliverText(String text){
        this.textPanel.appendText(text);
     }

}
```

TextListener is an interface that basically communicates between a button and the text area so that when a button is pressed the text inside of that button will appear in the text area.

Are either of these methods considered a better approach?  Is there actually a significant difference that I am just not aware of?

To me it seems that the second approach (where MainFrame implements TextListener) may be a more expensive way to handle things because we are passing an entire instance of MainFrame when all that is really needed is the information about TextListener. I imagine that in a larger program where MainFrame has a lot of components within it this would begin to be a problem.  Is this the correct way to think about it?  When I pass the argument "this" is a copy of MainFrame created wasting memory or is the same memory location of the original copy referenced?

Comment: when adding `this` you don't add the whole `frame` you just pass a *reference*... thus it would **not** increase the size...

Comment: there is no specific question here - how you design you application depends strongly on the purpose of you application - if you merely want to add some text onto a text field by pressing a button then you should only code that (first way) - if you have other purposes than *just adding text* maybe the other approach is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a simple example here, it really isn't a problem which you use.

There also a third option - create a seperate class that implements the interface on its own. That option allows a constructor to be defined for the listener. Sometimes that is useful.

Now, `this` is only a reference, so no copies are made, so no  more memory is used. I'd argue that not instantiating an anonymous class takes less resources.

Basically, how I was explained this approach was when there were many different Buttons all with `this` added as the interface. In the implementation of the interface method, the source of the button was checked using a if statement. That takes less resources than adding a separate anonymous classes for handling the same event for each component.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean in the last paragraph, many different buttons with this added as the interface.

Comment: See here.  2 buttons. 1 interface. You can additionally add an if statement to the actionPerformed method to check which button was clicked.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/MultiListenerProject/src/events/MultiListener.java

Answer (score 0):

If it's beneficial for your code to append text from other places except your button, go with the non-anonymous `void deliverText(String text)` method.

Otherwise go with the anon TextListener. The only drawback is that you'll have an extra `.class` file in your compiled set of classes/JAR.